# How to use FastMM in delphi expert(dll)

Tags: delphi, dll, fastmm

I made delphi expert(dll - delphi 5). I want to test my expert for memory leak.How to use FastMM for dll expert? Is it possible to use fastmm(for my dll) instead of the standard memory manager?

Comment: What should the "expert" term do signalize? Do you mean a Delphi IDE expert?

Comment: Yes. My dll is Delphi Ide expert.

Answer (score 4):

I **emphatically** advise you to use in any DLL running in the IDE's address space the very same memory manager used by  the respective version of the IDE. Madness lies the other way.

Comment: As well as madness, failure. It just doesn't work any other way.

Comment: @Worm Regards: What's not correct, that it doesn't work any other way? Yes, that's incorrect, you can do it. But in order to reconcile two different, *intrusive* allocators in the same process takes a lot, which is why I recommend avoiding it...

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you can't use FastMM in a Delphi 5 IDE expert, because it already uses ShareMem (BORLNDMM.DLL).

Comment: I know FastMM replaced the standard memory manager with the version of Delphi 2006.I was more interested in the issue tracking memory leaks.